# Creating and calling function in x86 assembly (AT&T syntax)

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

Please give me a very simple example of **creating a function and calling it in x86 Assembly (AT&T syntax).** Actaully I am trying to create a function that computes `factorial` of a number. This is what all I did :

```
#include<syscall.h>
#include<asm/unistd.h>
# Calculates Factorial, Argument is passed through stack
.text
.global _start
_start:
    pushl $5       #factorial of this value will be calculated
    call Fact
    movl %eax, %ebx #eax contains the result, Result is the return val of the program
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
    ret
Fact:
    popl %ebx     #Return address
    popl %edx
    movl $1, %ecx #Will be used as a counter
    movl $1, %eax #Result(Partial & complete) will be stored here
    LOOP:
        mul %ecx
        inc %ecx
        cmp %ecx, %edx
        jle LOOP
    pushl %ebx    #Restore the return address
    ret
```

I am getting **`Segmentation Fault`** error, again and again. I am using **GAS** on `Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code shouldn't crash. Make sure you assemble and link as 32 bits:

```
as --32 -o x.o x.s
ld -melf_i386 -o x x.o
```

The code is incorrect however. In particular:

- 'mul %ecx' alters %edx
- the arguments to 'cmp' must be reversed

Here is a corrected version:

```
        .text
        .global _start
_start:
        pushl $5
        call fact
        addl $4, %esp

        movl %eax, %ebx
        movl $1, %eax        # sys_exit
        int $0x80

fact:
        movl 4(%esp), %ecx
        movl $1, %eax
1:
        mul %ecx
        loop 1b
        ret
```

Run it with:

```
./x; echo $?
```